# PortoBuf-net Deserializes a double-sized version of the serialized double array

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract]
public class DataWrapper
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double[] Data = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dictionary<int, DataWrapper> serialized = new Dictionary<int, DataWrapper>();
        Dictionary<int, DataWrapper> deserialized;// = new Dictionary<int, OHLC>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            serialized.Add(i, new DataWrapper());                
        }
        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("dictionary", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize<Dictionary<int, DataWrapper>>(ms, serialized);
        }


        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream("dictionary", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, DataWrapper>>(ms);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("serialized {0} and deserialized {1}", serialized[0].Data.Length, deserialized[0].Data.Length);

        }
}
```

I am expecting to Deserialize an array of length 4, while I received an array of length 8. Is this a bug, or am I doing a mistake here?

Note that the code is meaningless. It's just an attempt to explain the issue I am facing in my real scenario

Comment: version of DLL is 2.0.0.622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no Protobuf-net expert, but this seems to be related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=261).  I suspect it is due to the fact that you're explicitly initializing the `double[]` to have 4 elements, and protobuf-net "appends" the additional 4 elements during deserialization.

As a workaround, you can set `SkipConstructor=true` the option in the `ProtoContract` and then it works as you expect:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]
```

Comment: `[ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)]` would also do the job. It seems it's not a bug, but a design decision, since Protobuf spec says that arrays should be *appended* if they aren't empty. This is not too "idiomatic" for C#, since mutating array size is usually considered bad practice.